# Typescript + Require.js + PIXI 6 - import attaches to window but undefined in main scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, pixi.js

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Pixi.js 5.3 to 6.0.0 and running into a weird issue. Previously I used `///<reference types='pixi.js'/>` just to allow the IDE to recognize Pixi types. This no longer appears to work since v6 has done away with the PIXI namespace.

Trying `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'` allows Typescript to recognize PIXI. But something strange is happening where PIXI gets attached to `window` instead of being defined within the module that imported it.

Here's the simplest example I can come up with. PIXI like any import should be attaching to and available in Main. Can anyone explain why PIXI is behaving differently here than any other import?

**index.html:**

`<script data-main='main' src='require.js'/>`

**Main.ts:**

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import * as FOO from 'Foo';
export class Main {
    public constructor() {
        console.log('window.PIXI',window.PIXI); //defined, contains all Pixi modules.
        console.log('PIXI',PIXI); //undefined
        
        console.log('window.FOO',window.FOO); //undefined
        console.log('FOO',FOO); //defined.
    }
}

new Main();
```

**Main.js (AMD)**

```
define(["require", "exports", "pixi.js", "Foo"], function (require, exports, PIXI, FOO) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    class Main {
        constructor() {
            console.log('window.PIXI', window.PIXI); //defined, contains all Pixi modules.
            console.log('PIXI', PIXI); //undefined
            console.log('window.FOO', window.FOO); //undefined
            console.log('FOO', FOO); //defined.
        }
    }
    exports.Main = Main;
    new Main();
});
```

**Foo.ts**

`export class Foo {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to add a shim for pixi.js in the require.js config. With this, imports work normally (although PIXI is still *also* attached to `window`).

```
require.config({
        shim: {
            'pixi.js': {
                exports: 'PIXI'
            }
        }
    });
```